# Como puedo ir acumulando los registros de estos datos? c++

Tags: c++, registro

Este es un programa en c++, el cual se colocan los registros de varias personas con sus datos correspondientes, pero tengo la duda de como poder mostrarlos cada registro que se va agregando y mostrarlos ordenadamente.

Es decir yo coloco los datos que pide para el registro de las personas, una vez agregados los datos, los muestra en una como tabla, y luego pide que se coloque la información de otra persona pero cuando lo muestra en pantalla solo muestra el de la nueva persona y quiero que también se muestre el de la persona anterior.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float cod;
    string nom, ape, dire, pue, res;
    float suel,sb, bf, Ingresos, Ingresos_Totales, bo, igss, irtra, Egresos, salali;
    char tele[9];
    float com;
do 
{
    cout<<"**********La Empresa 'Exclusivas S.A.'*********\n";
        
    cout<<"Ingrese el Codigo del Trabajador: ";
    cin>>cod;
    
    if(cod>0)
    {
        //resitro de empleados.
        cout<<"Ingrese el Nombre del Empleado: ";
        cin>>nom;
        cout<<"Ingrese el Apellido del Empleado: ";
        cin>>ape;
        cout<<"Ingrese EL Sueldo Base del Empleado: ";
        cin>>suel;
        cout<<"Ingrese la Direccion Del Trabajador: ";
        cin>>dire;
        cout<<"Ingrese EL Puesto del Empleado: ";
        cin>>pue;
        cout<<"Ingrese El Telefono del Empleado: ";
        cin>>tele;
        
        //calculos de ingresos
        sb= suel;
        com= sb*0.15;
        bf= 250;
        Ingresos= sb+com+bf;
        
        cout<<"EL Trabajador tiene alguna Bonificacion especial: ";
        cin>>res;
        if(res=="Si" || res=="si")
        {
            cout<<"¿Cual es la Bonificacion Especial? ";
            cin>>bo;
            
            Ingresos= sb+com+bf+bo;
            
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"No Tiene Ninguna Bonificacion Especial...";
        }
        
        //calculo de egresos.
        igss= suel*0.0483;
        irtra= suel*0.1267;
        Egresos= igss+irtra;
        
        //calculo total del sueldo liquido.
        salali=Ingresos - Egresos;
        
        cout<<"\n\nEL Codigo es: "<<cod;
        cout<<"\nEl Nombre es: "<<nom;
        cout<<"\nEl Apellido es: "<<ape;
        cout<<"\nEl Sueldo Base es: "<<suel;
        cout<<"\nLa Direccion es: "<<dire;
        cout<<"\nEL Puesto es: "<<pue;
        cout<<"\nEl Telefono es: "<<tele;
        cout<<"\nTotal de Ingresos: "<<Ingresos;
        cout<<"\nTotal de Egresos: "<<Egresos,
        cout<<"\nTotal De Sueldo liquido: "<<salali;
        
        cout<<"\n\n============================================== P L A N I L L A ====================================================";
        cout<<"\nCod     Nombres       Apellidos      Salario Base       Ingresos       Egresos      Sueldo Liquido       Comisiones\n";
        cout<<cod;
        cout<<"\t"<<nom;
        cout<<"\t\t"<<ape;
        cout<<"\t\t "<<suel;
        cout<<"\t\t "<<Ingresos;
        cout<<"\t"<<Egresos,
        cout<<"\t\t"<<salali;
        cout<<"\t\t"<<com;
        cout<<"\n====================================================================================================================\n\n";
    
    }
    
}while(cod>0);

    
}
```

[image: Compilación del programa]
[image: Compilación del programa]

[image: Compilación del programa (Se escribe 0 para que finalice)]